# MockK verifySequence not working because of object reference

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, mockk, sealed-class

It is common for me to work with a state class (a sealed class) that I use to control the state of my screen (let's say Success, Error and Loading). So I'd have something like:

```
sealed class State {
    object Loading: State()
    object Success : State()
    object Error : State()
}
```

Now, on some class, I have a propertie with this value that, in a certain flow, I set it to Loading and aftwards to Error. This I can check if that's the sequence this property is being set using `verifySequence` like this:

```
verifySequence {
    stateObserver.onChanged(State.Loading)
    stateObserver.onChanged(State.Success)
}
```

Now let's say my sealed classes have classes inside of it instead of objects and is a little more complex, like so:

```
sealed class NetworkResult<T> {
    class Success<T>(val data: T) : NetworkResult<T>()
    class Error<T>(val message: String) : NetworkResult<T>()
    class Loading<T> : NetworkResult<T>()
}
```

When I tried to check the sequency, my test fails because, since I'm using class and MockK makes a assert by referece:

```
verifySequence {
    stateObserver.onChanged(State.Loading())
    stateObserver.onChanged(State.Success(list))
}
```

Any idea how I can check this sequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a data class instead of a simple class:

```
sealed class NetworkResult<T> {
    data class Success<T>(val data: T?) : NetworkResult<T>()
    data class Error<T>(val message: String?) : NetworkResult<T>()
    data class Loading<T>(val nothing: Nothing? = null) : NetworkResult<T>()
}
```